# How to convert software RAID 1 into two RAID 0 drives

Tags: mdadm, disk-management

The /dev/nvme drives are allocated to a ZFS pool while `/dev/sda` & `/dev/sdb` are in software RAID 1. How am I able to remove this software RAID without any data loss or a required reboot if possible.

```
Disk /dev/nvme2n1: 3.5 TiB, 3840755982336 bytes, 7501476528 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZQLB3T8HALS-00007              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 63B6E337-3B79-C648-9CC1-AB9B1A767803

Device              Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme2n1p1       2048 7501459455 7501457408  3.5T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/nvme2n1p9 7501459456 7501475839      16384    8M Solaris reserved 1


Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 3.5 TiB, 3840755982336 bytes, 7501476528 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZQLB3T8HALS-00007              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E2B1ABF6-8F20-3E4D-9DE6-BB6A099164F2

Device              Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme1n1p1       2048 7501459455 7501457408  3.5T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/nvme1n1p9 7501459456 7501475839      16384    8M Solaris reserved 1


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 3.5 TiB, 3840755982336 bytes, 7501476528 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZQLB3T8HALS-00007              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 38A8941A-DCA5-E549-A796-4A0DA2B5E134

Device              Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048 7501459455 7501457408  3.5T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/nvme0n1p9 7501459456 7501475839      16384    8M Solaris reserved 1


Disk /dev/nvme3n1: 3.5 TiB, 3840755982336 bytes, 7501476528 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZQLB3T8HALS-00007              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: EF28D0ED-F30A-804D-87A0-F59C5E681FCA

Device              Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme3n1p1       2048 7501459455 7501457408  3.5T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/nvme3n1p9 7501459456 7501475839      16384    8M Solaris reserved 1


Disk /dev/sda: 447.1 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Disk model: INTEL SSDSC2KB48
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 14E4EB70-4780-46B5-A496-36204C410BC8

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1         34   1046527   1046494   511M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1046528  84932607  83886080    40G Linux RAID
/dev/sda3   84932608 125892607  40960000  19.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  125892608 937698991 811806384 387.1G Linux RAID
/dev/sda5  937698992 937703054      4063     2M Linux filesystem



Disk /dev/sdb: 447.1 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Disk model: INTEL SSDSC2KB48
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 563A4CDC-1C92-47AF-A32A-24EA97B301B5

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1         34   1046527   1046494   511M EFI System
/dev/sdb2    1046528  84932607  83886080    40G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb3   84932608 125892607  40960000  19.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb4  125892608 937698991 811806384 387.1G Linux RAID



Disk /dev/md2: 40 GiB, 42916118528 bytes, 83820544 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/md4: 387 GiB, 415510626304 bytes, 811544192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vg-data: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

/etc/fstab

```
UUID=c4408a1c-aa5b-4ce2-a9e8-1673660331e9       /       ext4    defaults        0       1
LABEL=EFI_SYSPART       /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
UUID=c90b3083-1b43-427c-8016-1d2406c36417       /var/lib/vz     ext4    defaults        0       0
UUID=e585755c-9908-4c01-a89b-d7fb1880b8f8       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
UUID=aea8f278-23a8-4ce0-97ca-4354720ca602       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
/dev/vg/swaplv       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
/dev/vg/swaplv2       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
```

swapon --show

```
NAME      TYPE       SIZE   USED PRIO
/dev/sdb3 partition 19.5G  19.5G   -2
/dev/sda3 partition 19.5G  19.5G   -3
/dev/dm-1 partition  247G 246.9G   -4
/dev/dm-2 partition  120G 104.8G   -5
```

vgdisplay

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  7
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               3
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               386.97 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              99065
  Alloc PE / Size       99065 / 386.97 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               e2YzU3-HzQe-DIqH-HGNr-tFqc-cWO1-K92uOR
```

Comment: Would you please enhance your question? You have posted much text without much information. Please reduce the amount of useless text and format your question accordingly.

Comment: What needs removing?

Comment: 80% unneeded information